# how conda instal pip (Theano) on ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, theano

I try to install theano use `conda install pip theano` but always failed. 
and I try to install using `sudo`, but when I try to import no module named theano.

Comment: `theano`, not `thenao`

Answer (score 0):

you either use:

```
conda install theano
```

or

```
pip install theano
```

conda and pip are two distinct installers that you need to have on your machine first; pip comes with python; conda is a separate tool, usually installed with an anaconda distribution

To check if you have conda installed, type `which conda` in your terminal.
to update conda, type `conda update conda`

Comment: is conda installed on your machine?